# Make responsive frame Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I tried to make repressive in Xamarin Forms.But no luck.He is my attempt.

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="20">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label x:Name="pol1" Text="some text" FontSize="Title" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="2" HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="10">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                    <Label Text="some text" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    <Label Text="some text" Grid.Row="3"/>
                    <Label Text="some text" Grid.Row="4"/>
                    <Label Text="some text some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text" Grid.Row="5"/>
                    <Label Text="some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text" Grid.Row="6"/>
                    <Label Text="some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text" Grid.Row="6"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

But frame doesn't scale to the text.I want to make it to scale to the end of the text.

Comment: if you are assigning the Label to a Grid cell, then the StackLayout is not needed

Comment: @Jason Yes work Thanks

Comment: You can write your solution in the answer or mark the right answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StackLayout usage and the indexing here is the problem. The parent layout will not be able to measure the size properly in this case. I have removed the unwanted StackLayouts to make it optimized. Now am able to get the desired result with the below code.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="pol1" Text="some text" FontSize="Title" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="2" HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                <Label Text="some text" Grid.Row="2"/>
                <Label Text="some text" Grid.Row="3"/>
                <Label Text="some text" Grid.Row="4"/>
                <Label Text="some text some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text" Grid.Row="5"/>
                <Label Text="some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text" Grid.Row="6"/>
                <Label Text="some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text" Grid.Row="6"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

I got the below output. I hope it helps you.

[image: Responsive frame]